# KeyError Appears when I convert datatypes despite the fact that I have that column in the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror

I have a dataframe with multiple columns that I imported like this:

```
Flash_Bookings = pd.read_excel(Bookings.xlsx',sheetname='FLASH Bookings' 
,index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Then I convert them to string, int or datetime format depending on what they are:

```
Flash_Bookings['BookingDate'] = pd.to_datetime(Flash_Bookings['BookingDate'], 
format='%Y-%m-%d')
Flash_Bookings['ContractNo'] = Flash_Bookings['ContractNo'].astype(str)
Flash_Bookings['Rep'] = Flash_Bookings['Rep'].astype(str)
```

They all work fine (I have other columns in there as well that I didn't include here that all were good except for one "Rep" so the error message I get is:

```
KeyError: 'Rep'
```

I even ran:

```
Flash_Bookings.dtypes
```

and get:

```
BookingDate           datetime64[ns]
ContractNo                    object
Rep                           object
```

so it works perfectly fine for ContractNo which is a string just like Rep.

Any ideas why Rep would not work and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an extra space in the header

Try:

```
Flash_Bookings.columns = Flash_Bookings.columns.str.strip()
```

Then call

```
Flash_Bookings['Rep'] = Flash_Bookings['Rep'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that resolved the problem. Never thought it would be something that simple.